# How to get the text of the selected radio button using Selenium 2 PHPUnit

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, automated-tests

I am trying to get the text "Standard Gloss Cardstock" in my Selenium 2 program. I want to get the text of the selected radio button using Xpath.

```html
<div class="calculator-paper-radio">
  <label>
    <input id="attr1_22272" class="calculator-paper-input" type="radio" checked="checked" value="22272" name="attr1"        style="padding:0px;">
    <span id="div_attr1_22272" style="padding-top:2px;">Standard Gloss Cardstock</span>
    <span class="calculator-paper-desc">Our most popular option! Gloss finish for vibrant colors and high contrast.</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code

```
String xpath = "//span[@id='div_attr1_22272']";
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText();
```

I'm not sure how exactly get text in PHP. But ""//span[@id='div_attr1_22272']" is the correct xpath locator

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's best to include some explanation as well as to *why* this is the correct code, not just the code itself. Please see: [answer]

Comment: To be exact..I want my program to get the text of the selected radio button

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the ids are generated randomly. so we can't use them.
You can use one of the following XPaths:

```
'(//input[@type="radio"])' 
'(//*[@type="radio"])'
```